# Exclude URLs with certain extensions from being redirected to index page

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a set of rewrite rules that redirect all pages that don't exist to the index of my site:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Basically, the current rule is redirecting every URL that is not a directory or file to index.php, so `www.example.com/thispageexists`, `www.example.com/thispagedoesntexist` and also `www.example.com/missingfile.xml` go to the index.php page.  If the URL doesn't exist in the CMS, that will trigger a 404 error back to the user.

I'd like to exclude any URL with certain file extensions, say `.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|xml|html|swf|ttf|eot)$`, from being redirected, even if the file does not exist.

I still want to continue directing pages that don't exist to index.php but **not** if the url ends in any of those file extensions.

Comment: Exclude from what?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: No need to downvote if you don't understand. just ask

Comment: Or you could ask a comprehensible question to begin with.  Does my edit of the question represent what you want to achieve?

Comment: And look!  A good question begets a good answer in no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple:

```
RewriteRule \.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|xml|html|swf|ttf|eot)$ - [NC,L]
```

Just place it in a right place (as order of rules matters): for example, **before** this line: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

**P.S.**
The `[NC]` flag is unnecessary for your rules with such (`^.*$`) pattern (it makes no difference at all).